# Solid line and greek letters in plot MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

**So basically I tried looking online and in my textbook but I can't figure out how to insert the greek symbol theta into the legend box and axis **

```
x = linspace(0,2*pi)

figure
plot(x,sin(x),x,sin(x-0.25),'r--')
legend('sin(\theta)','sin(\theta-0.25)')
xlabel(' 0 <= \theta <=2 \pi')
ylabel('fx')
box on 
grid on
```

Comment: how about [encoding it](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/greekchart.html)?

Comment: what do you mean? ..sorry, kind of new to this

Comment: It works fine in Octave, I am surprised it doesn't work in MATLAB

Comment: I don't know matlab, but try using, say, the html 'version' of theta (write &Theta;)

Comment: What version of matlab are you using? It's working for me in 2014b

Comment: Well its working for me in 2013b...

Comment: don't know why it isnt working, I know it should

Comment: is it maybe the settings on my figure??

Comment: Try using `xlabel(' <= \theta','interpreter','tex');`

Comment: that didn't work, I think it might be the settings in this computer

Comment: is there a certain setting I nedd to put matlab in to see greek symbols??

Comment: Just to clarify, does `\pi` work, but `\theta` does not? There isn't a particular setting that you need, it should work out of the box

Comment: neither of them work, \theta shows q and \pi shows p

Comment: Ah HA! That means that it is interpreting it, but that the font your figure is using uses q and p instead of greek letters! Are you using any non-standard fonts? Is it possible that your computer doesn't have the standard windows/mac fonts?

Comment: Currently I am using the Linux OS

Comment: I do have a Windows back home...Do you think that is the problem??

Comment: I have the same problem on Linux; it has to do with the fonts. @Trogdor is right: MATLAB is interpreting the TeX just fine, but the system isn't rendering it properly. Printing the figure to EPS should still work fine (because that ultimately relies on the EPS reader to render the fonts). I've also found that R2014b somehow gets it to work on my Linux machine.